# How to do multiple calculations with set /a in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

E.g. if I want to do the following calculation, how to make it work?

```
set /A math=%%N+%code%+2*3/7
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit to show the complete relevant code that is not working, and what result you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to do multiple calculations with set /a in batch?

`,` is used to separate expressions. An example of it's use would be:

```
set /a "_num=2,_result=_num*5"
```

So:

```
set /A math=%%N+%code%+2*3,4/7
```

is an invalid expression.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [Incomplete documentation for SET /A](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1649)

Comment: It all depends on context. `set /A math=%%N+%code%+2*3,4/7` could be valid syntax within a FOR loop.

Comment: @dbenham Oh. Do you have an example?

Comment: Within a batch script, assume code is defined as 4, then `for %%N in (1) do (set /a math=%%N+%code%+2*3,4/7)"` is valid. The first expression assigns 11 to math. The second expression of `4/7` yields 0, but it is simply discarded because it is not assigned to a variable. The SET /A statement can be on its own line, but I can't show that in a comment.

Comment: @dbenham Thanks, what is the mismatched `"` for?

Comment: for stupidity ;-) I intended for a quote before math, or no quotes at all, but it works either way.